# Asymptotic Approximation of Integrals

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, asymptotics, integration-by-parts, approximate-integration

Determine the asymptotic behaviour of the following integral:

$(1)$  :  $f(\epsilon)=f(0)+ \int^{\epsilon}_{0}f'(x) dx$ as $\epsilon  \rightarrow 0$

I have in my notes that:

$(2)$
 :    $f(\epsilon)=f(0) + \left[(x-\epsilon)f'(x)\right]^{\epsilon}_{0} + \int^{\epsilon}_{0}(\epsilon - x)f''(x) dx$
Then
$f(\epsilon)=\sum^{N}_{n=0}\dfrac{\epsilon^{n}f^{n}(0)}{n!} + \dfrac{1}{N!}\int^{\epsilon}_{0}(\epsilon - x)^{N}f^{(n+1)}(x) dx$ (provided remainder is small)

I understand that we need to use integration by parts to obtain an asymptotic approximation however I dont understand how to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$

Comment: From $(1)$ to $(2)$ it's literally integrated by parts. And specifically, for fixed $\epsilon$ you have $$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} f'(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\epsilon} f'(x)d(x-\epsilon) = \left[(x-\epsilon)f'(x) \right]_{0}^{\epsilon} - \int_{0}^{\epsilon} (x-\epsilon)f''(x)$$, from such observation you have your formula

Comment: (I forgot a $dx$ in the last integral)

Comment: @user8469759 why do we put $d(x-\epsilon)$ for fixed $\epsilon$?

Comment: You fix $\epsilon$ because of your definition of $f(\epsilon)$. Secondly the observation is that $d(x-\epsilon) = dx - d\epsilon = dx$ (because indeed $\epsilon$ is fixed we have it's differential is $0$, like a constant basically). So you have the identity $dx = d(x - \epsilon)$.

Comment: Or you can view $dx = 1 \cdot dx$ and one of the primitives of $g(x) = 1$ is $x - \epsilon$.